# ArcGIS Attribute Image Download

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, esri-geodatabase, image

I am creating a database which has to consist of images (the images are older survey PDF plans that I have been saved as jpgs). I understand the feature has to be in a geodatabase, then the attribute column has to be a raster type. My problem is when the image is downloaded into my table in Editor, it comes out very blurry. The quality in the original jpg is fine. Just curious if there is a way to help this...

Comment: What were the precise steps that you performed when doing this?